# How to parallel points2network (function in shp2graph) R?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, gps, gis, r-sf

I have a London road network downloaded from OS and saved in shapefile format (`london_net`),
and a set of sampled GPS points (`sample.pt`).

I want to use `points2network` function in `shp2graph` (the paper link: https://www.mdpi.com/2220-9964/7/8/293) to snap my 30,000 GPS points to the nearest road segment.

the function is fully operational but takes about 1.5 hours to run (I only sampled 30k points from my dataset so the size of the original one is much larger).

Given that case, I'd like to know how to parallel this function? so speed it up.

here are the codes I tried:

```
#### library ####
library(raster)
library(shp2graph)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#BNG CRS#
bng <- "+init=epsg:27700" 
#### read shp. #####

london_net <- shapefile('...') %>% spTransform(.,CRS(bng))
sample.pt <- shapefile('...') %>%  spTransform(.,CRS(bng)) %>% st_as_sf()

#### get coordinates ####

ptsxy <- st_coordinates(pt.in_cam)

### point 2 network ###
Start_time <- Sys.time()
pt2nt1 <- points2network(ntdata = london_net, pointsxy = ptsxy, Detailed = T,
                         ELComputed = T, approach = 2, ea.prop = rep(0, ncol(london_net)))

End_time <- Sys.time()
End_time - Start_time
```

```
Time difference of 1.670295 hours
```